# Existing forms:In Django

Tags: django

I have an pre-built HTML form and I need to reuse it with Django form class (django.forms), So how do I incorporate my HTML form with Django form class. for example

**HTML:**

```
<li id="foli11" class="">
 <label class="desc" id="title11" for="Field11">
  Username
 <span id="req_0" class="req">*</span>
 </label>
 <div class="col">
  <input id="Field11" name="Field11" type="text" class="field text medium" value="" maxlength="255" tabindex="11" /> 
 </div>
</li>
```

How do I map this HTML in to Django form class, I know that it can be done by modifying Django form fields according to this HTML. But I guess it's a time consuming approach,so I would like to know that is there any easy and time saving solutions for this issue.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Extend the django forms.Form class and write to it your own form.as_my_ul similar to form.as_p:

Here is the implementation of as_p: http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/forms/forms.py#L227

```
def as_p(self):
"Returns this form rendered as HTML <p>s."
    return self._html_output(
    normal_row = u'<p%(html_class_attr)s>%(label)s %(field)s%(help_text)s</p>',
    error_row = u'%s',
    row_ender = '</p>',
    help_text_html = u' %s',
    errors_on_separate_row = True)
```